# проверка сохранения файла php

Tags: php

Найдена одна особенность в счетчике скачиваний файлов.

При нажатии кнопки "отмена" в диалоге сохранения файла счетчик все равно накручивается (чем тогда этот счетчик отличается от счетчика кликов по ссылке?).

Примерный код:

```
if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
    $filename = $_GET['file'];

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysql_connect_error());
    }

    $select = "SELECT counter FROM test_counter WHERE name='$filename'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $select);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $counter = $row['counter'];
        $counter += 1;
        send_file();
        $update = "UPDATE `test_counter` SET `counter`=$counter WHERE name='$filename'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $update);
    }
    else
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `test_counter`(`name`, `counter`) VALUES ('$filename', 1)");

    mysqli_close($conn);

}

function send_file() {
    $file = __DIR__.'\\download.php';
    header('X-SendFile: ' . realpath($file));
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
}
```

Собственно вопрос в том, можно ли как-то проверить, что пользователь действительно сохранил файл (а не нажал "отмена"), сделав что-то вроде (ну или каким-то другим способом):

```
$dialog = send_headers();

if ($dialog->get_result() == OKAY) {
    update_counter();
}
```

Comment: Для этого потребуется троян.

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics не стоит писать бред

Comment: как вариант: отловить на клиенте нажатие отмены и отправить на сервер ajax-запрос, на сервере ловим запрос и откатываем счетчик на 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, используя загрузку по частям в PHP.

Выглядит примерно следующим образом:

```
// send file (it shows save file dialog)
header('Cache-control: private');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filepath));
header('Content-Disposition: filename='.$filename);
flush();

$file = fopen($filepath, "r");

while(!feof($file))
{
    // send the current file part to the browser
    print fread($file, round($download_rate * 1024));
    // flush the content to the browser
    flush();
    // sleep one second
    sleep(1);
}

// if all are right and file was downloaded
if (feof($file)) {
    update_current_counter_or_insert_new_one_in_DATABASE();
}

fclose($file);
```

Эта [ссылка](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.readfile.php#83653) помогла при поиске решения.